# What does this GIT command do?

Tags: git

I'm trying to understand what this GIT command does:

`git push origin master:release_candidate --force`

I know `git push origin master` pushes the local master to the remote origin.

I would like to know the `:release_candidate --force` part.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: `man git push` or `man git-push`

Answer (score 4):

The `:release_candidate` part is a remote refspec. What that does is push *your* branch called `master` to the *remote* branch called `release_candidate`. Normally, without `:`, the local branch is pushed to the remote branch with the same name.

The `--force` option pushes even if doing so would lose commits at the remote. This is fine if what you want to do is forcibly overwrite whatever was in the `release_candidate` branch before.

Answer (score 1):

Let's read the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) and extract the pieces that explain your command:

> `git push [-f | --force] [<repository> [<refspec>…​]]`

*(I omitted the myriad of options not present in the question)*

> **OPTIONS**
>
> `<repository>`
>
> The "remote" repository that is destination of a push operation. This parameter can be either a URL or the name of a remote.
>   `refspec>…`
>
> Specify what destination ref to update with what source object. The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an optional plus `+`, followed by the source object `<src>`, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`.
>
> The `<src>` is often the name of the branch you would want to push, but it can be any arbitrary "SHA-1 expression", such as `master~4` or `HEAD`
>
> The `<dst>` tells which ref on the remote side is updated with this push. Arbitrary expressions cannot be used here, an actual ref must be named.
>
> The object referenced by `<src>` is used to update the `<dst>` reference on the remote side. By default this is only allowed if `<dst>` is not a tag (annotated or lightweight), and then only if it can fast-forward `<dst>`.

...

> **-f**
>   **--force**
>
> Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it. [...]
>
> This flag disables these checks, and can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it with care.

---

To sum everything up, your command:

```
git push origin master:release_candidate --force
```

uses the local branch `master` to update the branch `release_candidate` of the `origin` remote. If the local branch `master` is a descendant of the remote branch `origin/release_candidate` then the `--force` flag is not needed. Otherwise, without `--force` the push is rejected by the remote server.

For a detailed discussion (with examples) about what happens when you use `--force`, please read the section [Notes about fast forwards](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_note_about_fast_forwards) from the documentation.